# How to remove "Select" on the list

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I put the "Select" as placeholder in select option but not on the list of the dropdown when you click it? Any idea?

Thanks!

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="name">Hours of Operation:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
        <select class="form-control" name="hours-of-operation" class="selectpicker">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option value="Business Hours">Business Hours</option>
            <option value="After Business Hours">After Business Hours</option>
            <option value="24/7">24/7</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you _not_ want it to not be in the options list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `value=""` and abort the event handler if no value is selected.

```
<select class="form-control" name="hours-of-operation" class="selectpicker">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Business Hours">Business Hours</option>
    <option value="After Business Hours">After Business Hours</option>
    <option value="24/7">24/7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Set it `disabled`. Once the user clicks the `select`, they HAVE to choose an option.

Comment: @tymeJV Setting `<option disabled>` will preclude the "Select.." option from being the default option (effectively hiding it until the user expands the drop-down)

Comment: @KevinBoucher -- Not if you set it to `selected` as well :) http://jsfiddle.net/Jg4sA/

Comment: @tymeJV Confirmed. Very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend doing it when select's value actually changes, not when it's merely clicked. The idea is to remove the first option element from the select. Like this:

```
$('select').one('change', function(e) {
   $(this).find('option').first().remove(); 
});
```

There are obviously many different ways to achieve the same thing, so take your pick.

Here's an working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/h7aVC/1/

Comment: @AlyssaReyes: Sorry, forgot to add the link, plus the example wasn't very good so I fixed that as well.